# How to create a timer that starts on a certain condition, and counts to 15 seconds? (C#)

Tags: c#, if-statement, dll, timer

I am creating a C# library, and am looking to create a timer that starts once a certain condition is met. Then, I want the timer to count up to 15 seconds, and once 15 seconds is reached, another action is performed. It would look something like this:

```
if (condition is met)
{
    //start timer
}

if (timer == 15 seconds)
{
    //do something
    //reset timer for next time that condition is met
}
```

Any help on how to do this in C# is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//using System.Timers;
```

How to insitantiate:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(); //Outside the method
```

Inside the method that the timer subscribes

```
timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
timer.Interval = 15000; //number in milisecinds  
timer.Enabled = true;
```

The OnElapsedTime EventHandler

```
private async void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    //Do Something
}
```

**Notes:**

1. It is important to `using System.Timers;`
2. The event will run every 15000 (15 seconds)
3. Code inside the event handler will be executed automatically (not need for condition).

Comment: @coder5777 happy for that, if you like to mark the answer as accepted I will be happy, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Task.Delay`.

```
if (condition is met)
{
   // Wait for 15 seconds
   await Task.Delay(15000);
   
   //do something
}
```